# Radiosity global illumination shadow`s edges jitter, being not straight

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, lighting

I'm implementing radiosity illumination technique. I have some static scene that I want to precompute and then show and move inside it. So not that realtime, but must work on mobiles.
So the geometry is being split and the light bounces, but the shadow edges look bad:

[image: pic]

The geometry is being split using triangles:

[image: the pic with the triangulation]

As their edges don't align along the shade it looks not that nice. And the samples in the internets don't have that (while some do have). So I am probably missing something.

Maybe I should find the shadow edges and force triangulation to create line along those edges. But it is not that easy to find them and they could have complex shape, and there could be many lights further multiplying the number of triangulation restrictions. More dense triangulation is unlikely to help (tried that), the edge jittering will be on a smaller scale, but more intense. It could help if WAY more triangles were created and the output blurred. But as this is radiosity, increasing the number of triangles dramatically affects the performance. The scene in the pic is very simple, it is good for demonstration, but we need (and have) much more complex scenes/views, with models, 3d perspective view etc.
The triangles showed are in fact further subdivided into four each for better colour interpolation, but these are the units of the light bouncing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get a hard shadow from a sparsely tessellated geometry. So if you have a point light that should generate hard shadows:

- Apply your radiosity algorithm.
- Subtract the direct light from the solution, so it would have only the indirect light contribution.
- When you render the scene, use the radiosity solution for indirect lighting and a classical technique (like high-resolution shadow maps) for hard shadows.

Alternatively you can indeed perform an adaptive subdivision. See [GPU Gems 2. Chapter 39. Global Illumination Using Progressive Refinement Radiosity#Adaptive Subdivision](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter39.html) for loose description and references.

Comment: I don't need hard shadows. I only want shades look like shades. Probably really radiosity should be used mostly for the indirect light.

Comment: Then use area lights. It will smooth the things out. Otherwise everything I said still applies (no, you cannot solve your problem by doing some smart tessellation, especially when you have multiple lights).

Comment: Thanks, that gives some ideas to think about. Can you please advice some reading about area lights? As little as I know they are rather kind of a bunch of point lights, and that sounds slow.

Comment: Not in radiosity solver -- they are just a geometry that emits light. So if today your radiosity solves for `Lout = D*∫Lin` for each face, then you need to change it to `Lout = Ls + D*∫Lin` where `Ls` is the light that the face emits on its own. The "bunch of point lights" approach is used when the only thing at your disposal is a rendering engine that supports only point lights...

Comment: Uhm, isn't it supposed to NOT be calculated using those faces? I think it is closer to what it is now. There can be geometry that initially emits light. Also it is kind of in the radiosity solver.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. If this is what you currently do then probably your light geometry is still much smaller than the grid tessellation. Other things to consider: use a uniform grid, perhaps even an sparse octree. This way even if the edges are aliased they won't be jagged.

Comment: This light is point. But for bigger lights the effect is still there, cause, say, near the walls the shade must be sharp. Drawing direct light without tesselation and then adding indirect should do the trick. The question is how to draw direct light. I could use an advice here.

Uniform grid is uniform, thus too dense and too sparse, and it is rectangular. And there is non rectangular geomety and something should be done about that. While non point lights do look better. I've tried adding regular grid points so the triangulation used them, but had no significant improvement in how it looks.